Pagination is not working in Spring Boot via Oracle11g
I am trying to use Pagination in Spring boot application and using Oracle11g but it is giving me below error.
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select au1_0.user_id,au1_0.created_on,au1_0.created_by,au1_0.email,au1_0.first_name,au1_0.last_login_date,au1_0.last_name,au1_0.msisdn,au1_0.password,au1_0.security_code,au1_0.status from user au1_0 offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only] [ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Please help me as I am new in Spring boot. Thank you in advance.
I am trying to use Pagination in Spring boot application and using Oracle11g
Controller
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 1);
Page<AdminUser> auList = adminUserService.getAllUsers(pageRequest);

Service
public Page<AdminUser> getAllUsers(Pageable pageable);

ServiceImpl
@Override
public Page<AdminUser> getAllUsers(Pageable pageable) {     
    return adminUserRepository.findAll(pageable); 
}


it would be helpful if you could post some piece of code you tried.

Hi Kms. I put some code of controller and service

Oracle 11g does not support the syntax offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only; that was introduced in Oracle 12. You need to configure Spring Boot to use the correct dialect when generating queries. You may also need to check that Oracle 11g is supported and, if not, either downgrade the version of Spring Boot to one that does support it or (better) upgrade your database.

Thank you @MT0 for your valuable comment. Is there any other way to implement paging in Spring boot web application which is using Oracle11g?

You do not want to find a different method of implementing pagination. As I said in the previous comment, "You need to configure Spring Boot to use the correct dialect when generating queries."

need more clarification on question

No thanks I changed the Springboot version and now it is working fine. Thank you guys for your valuable support.

Oracle 11g does not support the syntax offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only; that was introduced in Oracle 12.
You need to configure Spring Boot to use the org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect (11g uses the same dialect as 10g) which will generate pagination queries using the ROWNUM psuedo-column rather than OFFSET ... FETCH .... Note: this dialect is deprecated and has been removed in the latest versions in preference for org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect.
If Spring Boot is using the latest version of Hibernate then it is only compatible with Oracle 19 and later and you may need to downgrade to an earlier version to support Oracle 11g (or else upgrade your database).
